# Dart Editor Not Listing Relative Local Libraries

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I've been working through all of the provided Dart Tutorials on dartlang.org

When finished, i started working on writing some of my own libraries inside the project.

Project structure based off: https://github.com/dart-lang/deploy-codelab

The Dart Editor has a problem with importing anything not inside package: or dart:

Typing `import "";` and trying ctrl-space only shows package, and dart.

Manually typing `import '../lib/my_library.dart' show SomeClass; // does work`

Problem:
I should be able to traverse the relative file path, or import from some type of global local library

Platform: MacOSX
Dart Editor version 1.1.1.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This seems mostly the problem with DartEditor, that autocompletion doesn't list libraries to import.

You have three ways of importing libraries:

```dart
import 'dart:io';  // for Dart internal libraries
import 'package:angular/angular.dart'; // for all packages (where angular.dart is in angular/lib/angular.dart
import 'src/my_library.dart';
```

If you want to import from the library directory of the same package where your application code is use this form as shown in your question it's IMHO better to use the `package:` version too.

```dart
import 'package:mypackage/my_library' show SomeClass
```